# Android Installing ask for enable debugging permission

Tags: android, debugging, permissions, publishing

While preparing my app for publishing, I discovered that "enable debugging" under development tools permission is needed, although I removed all breakpoints and disabled debugging in Mainfest android:debuggable="false"

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I didnt have any breakpoints and android:debuggable was false. However I did restart my device and it basically did the trick.

So if you didnt try to restart it, i'd give it a try

Also make sure you are starting the app with: project-> run As -> Android Application